# How to Check for "enabled_notification_listeners" Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to check that either my application's service is Enabled or Not in **"Notification Access"**.

I am using this code to check this. The code is running fine on **Nougat**, but it crashes on **Marshmallow**. How can I do that on **Marshmallow**?

```
android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners").contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())
```

This is the **Error in LogCat**:

```
12-06 15:28:02.905 4428-4428/com.inetsoho.app.SkyChat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.inetsoho.app.SkyChat, PID: 4428
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4740)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.inetsoho.app.SkyChat.ui.activities.authorization.LandingActivity.SignUpPhoneNumberOnClickListener(LandingActivity.java:110)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to get our package have notification listener or not. This Function will returns True or false.

```
boolean hasNotificationAccess()
    {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        String enabledNotificationListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners");
        String packageName = this.getPackageName();

        // check to see if the enabledNotificationListeners String contains our package name
        return !(enabledNotificationListeners == null || !enabledNotificationListeners.contains(packageName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check your service directly:

```
context?.applicationContext?.let {

  val componentName = ComponentName(it, YourNotificationListenerService::class.java)

  val enabledNotificationListeners: String? =
                Settings.Secure.getString(it.contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners")

  return enabledNotificationListeners != null && enabledNotificationListeners.contains(
                componentName.flattenToString())
}
```

The downside is that you need access to the context.